# Counting individual rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following loan schema:

```
mysql> select * from borrower;
+----------+---------+
| name     | loan_id |
+----------+---------+
| Adams    | L16     |
| Curry    | L93     |
| Hayes    | L15     |
| Jackson  | L14     |
| Jones    | L17     |
| Smith    | L11     |
| Smith    | L23     |
| Williams | L17     |
+----------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to calculate the total number of loans, every person has taken. I thought self-join is the solution to this and I tried the following query:

```
select T1.name, count(T2.name) from borrower T1, borrower T2 where T1.name = T2.name;
```

But I get weird results as following:

```
mysql> select T1.name, count(T2.name) from borrower T1, borrower T2 where T1.name = T2.name;
+-------+----------------+
| name  | count(T2.name) |
+-------+----------------+
| Adams |             10 |
+-------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It seems like a simple `GROUP BY name` is what you want. Why would you want to do a self-join?

Comment: ^^ Right - the join is unnecessary. But you're run afoul of MySQL's lenience with the `GROUP BY` (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select name, count(name) from borrower
group by name
```